# notepad++: How to reset all the setting to default ones?

Tags: notepad++, default-settings

I change settings a lot. Now, I think I've played with Notepad++ too much. Now how can I reset the settings ?

btw, I don't want to uninstall, then install again. that's not so "superuser"-ish, right?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The easiest way to reset to defaults would probably be to delete the configuration files.  This also means you can back them up if you ever want them back.

Notepad++ uses the follwowing path for settings using a default installation settings:

```
%APPDATA%\Notepad++
```

In that directory there are several `.xml` configuration files.  Remove the ones you want to reset and restart Notepad++.

Comment: This worked great with notepad++ version 6.5.4

Comment: This is a more useful path:  C:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Roaming\notepad++

Comment: Removing the 'config.xml' resets it to default layout.

Comment: @Ed999 The accepted solution worked perfectl out-of-the-box for me, I don't see what your suggestion adds.

Comment: I expect the suggested solution works well enough for some users, and may even work for version 6.5.4, but to locate the necessary folder using Windows Explorer it's necessary to know the actual location of the folder. And it helps to differentiate the folder from any backup folder the user may have set in 'Options'.

Answer (score 12):

Go to

C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\notepad++

(type your username instead of "Administrator" in the above path)

Delete the file "stylers.xml".

Restart Notepad++

Comment: The answer is right. Just always remember about environment variables. `%appdata%` makes life all of us easier ;)

Comment: Weirdly enough this turned everything orange for me.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to do using the following steps:

1. Go to settings
2. Go to style configurator
3. Then you can see there is an option call select theme.
4. Select default theme and save it.
5. Close the notepad and restart.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question (until there is some Woo-Doo action behind this)

Comment: This was immediately useful. 3 seconds versus all the labor involved in every answer above it.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone has the same issue as me: If you have a Backupfolder set up in Options you have to delete the files mentioned above from that folder!

Comment: you can see the backup directory location in `$env:APPDATA/Notepad++/cloud/choice` (Powershell)

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me to remove all color styling:

1. Ctrl-A to select and highlight entire document
2. Right click
3. Remove style
4. Clear all styles

Answer (score 0):

If during installation you decided to don't use %APPDATA%, configuration xml files will be in notepad++ installation directory. This is frequent 4USB installation profile.

Comment: Sorry, its not making sense to me.

Answer (score -2):

just backup config.xml and than erase it to bring defaults back..

Comment: This answer does add nothing new in comparison to the above answers.