# Notepad++ does not un-minimize/restore when "Edit in Notepad++"

Tags: notepad++

The context menu on the Windows Explorer, item "Edit in Notepad++" does not unminimized/restore the running Notepad++ instance.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what seems to work:
Settings>>Preferences 
In the MISC. category on the left,
on the right hand side check: "Minimize to system tray"

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**: [How to reset settings](https://superuser.com/questions/540286/notepad-how-to-reset-all-the-setting-to-default-ones)