# notepad++ : How to reset all the setting to default ones?

Tags: notepad++

I accidentally deleted some parts like hashtag **For example**. I would like to reset my notepad settings to default, how do i do that? Please help me thanks!

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/540286/

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the configuration files in %APPDATA%\Notepad++. They are with extension .xml.

On some versions of notepad++ you might need to go to C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\notepad++ and delete the .xml files.

If you have selected don't use AppData during installation, than these configuration files will be in the Notepad++ installation folder.

Everything is in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLUqbuM2-14) and its description(in Russian and English).
The video is made by me as a part of our free tutorial creation service, where anyone can ask for a tutorial video and we will make it.

Comment: Thanks for answering, i'm kind of new on this app. Do you recommend selecting the dont use AppData during installation?

Comment: If you need to make Notepad++ portable or use it from a flash drive, you can select it.

Comment: Thanks, is there any way i can contact you just in case i mess some settings up?

Comment: I don't know if this is allowed on superuser and its variation sites. Otheriwise there are a lot of ways. I will create a video how to do it later. You can always commet here.

Comment: You can see all the steps and how to reset the settings in the video. Also you can see how to use the portable version and how to reset the settings of the portable version. Please read the video description.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLUqbuM2-14

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a stupid answer here, but just uninstall it and re-install it, unless it gives you an option to keep settings when you uninstall, which you can usually deny, it should remove all settings, and you will have the default ones when you re-install it, I am not at the PC to test it out, but this should work, and will save you messing with things

Comment: Thanks for answering, will do it!