# How to prevent notepad++ from replacing < and > with &lt; and &gt;

Tags: notepad++, html, replacement

I have just updated notepad++ win64 to version 8.5..

When I type `<` or `>` into html files, notepad++ is replacing those characters with `&lt;` and `&gt;`

For example, when I type `<b>`, notpad++ is changing that to `&lt;b&gt;` which parses properly but not desired.

Existing `<` and `>` characters in the files are unchanged.

I've tried to find a setting or maybe something in the html dictionary which is causing this kind of live replacment. Have not yet found a way to disable this.

My guess is it was caused by my fat fingers or a cat walking on the keyboard toggling a setting in notepad++ which I have been unable to reset.

Would someone please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: I've never seen this behaviour, it works fine for me.

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed? Also, did you try calling up and resetting the whole config (see [here](https://superuser.com/a/540297/368970).)

Answer (score 2):

Thank for that helpful information!

I found the culprit; NPPTextFX plugin has some settings whose status is NOT shown in its menu!

NPPTextFX.xml has these lines, which were set to 1 and I changed to 0. Problem solved.

```
[Settings]
AutoCloseBrace=0
AutoCloseHTMLtag=0
AutoSpace2Tab=0
AutoConvertHTML=0
```